# Sending multiple HTTP requests in Node.js: Not receiving any responses or timeouts

Tags: node.js, http, mediawiki, keep-alive, wikipedia-api

I am trying to process Wikipedia articles, and want to receive a list of all Wikipedia articles. In order to do this I am frequently sending http requests to the Wikipedia API, which allows you to receive 500 titles at time and also returns an *apcontinue* string, which, when used in the following request, returns title starting from that string.

In order to do this, I am using the *agentkeepalive* module:

```
var http = require('http');
var Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

var keepaliveAgent = new Agent({
  keepAlive: true,
  maxSockets: 5,
  timeout: 5000,
  keepAliveTimeout: 3000
});
```

To send an http request to Wikipedia, I use the following code:

```
function wikipediaApiCall(params, callback) {
  var options = {
    host: 'en.wikipedia.org',
    path: '/w/api.php?' + createParamString(params),
    method: 'GET',
    agent: keepaliveAgent
  };

  var callbackFunc = function(response) {
    var err;
    var str = '';

    if (('' + response.statusCode).match(/^5\d\d$/)) {
      err = new Error('Server error');
    }

    //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('error', function (e) {
      err = new Error('Request error');
    });

    response.on('timeout', function () {
      err = new Error('Timeout');
      response.abort();
      callback(err);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      var obj = JSON.parse(str);

      if (obj.warnings) {
        err = new Error('Request error');
      }

      callback(err, obj);
    });
  }

  var req = http.request(options, callbackFunc);
  req.setTimeout(5000);

  req.on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err, null);
    return;
  });

  req.on('timeout', function () {
    err = new Error('Timeout');
    response.abort();
    callback(err);
  });

  req.on('finish', function(){
    console.log('ended');
  });

  req.end();
}
```

However, after sending between 16 and 20 request, I am not getting any response, but my request also does not time out.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update**

The request I send to Wikipedia contains the following parameters:

```
  var params = {
    list: 'allpages',
    aplimit: limit,
    apfrom: from,
    continue: cont,
    // apfilterredir: 'nonredirects'
  };
```

Interestingly, after leaving out the `nonredirects` setting, I was able to send and receive up to 330 requests, but no more than that.

**Update 2**

I was able to register a `finished` event. It appears to be fired for the request that is failing as well. I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, this was unclear. By 500 titles at a time I mean that I request a page with 500 titles from Wikipedia at a time, not 500 concurrent requests.

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're using to handle and perform the requests? (I removed my old comment because I couldn't edit it anymore, it had a typo)

Comment: I updated the question now, showing the code used for the request.

Comment: Have you tried _not_ using `agentkeepalive`? Also, you're not listening for `error` events on the `req` object and since you're calling `setTimeout()` on `req`, you should also listen for `timeout` events on `req`. Those things most likely won't fix your problem, but still worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I added listeners for error events on the request. The issue still persists. Not using `agentkeepalive` further reduces the number of requests I can send.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a bot flag to have higher API limits. Maybe there are too many requests in parallel; WMF recommendation is to make requests serially in case of such big tasks. Also, you should use the maxlag parameter with low values, per WMF API Etiquette.